# Open link in WKWebView as fast as SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, wkwebview

How to open a link in WKWebview as fast as it loads in SKSafariViewController. WKWebView loading is slower and not incremental. SKSafariViewController loads content incrementally. I cannot use SKSafariViewController as I need to customise the UI, don't need the default top and bottom bars that SKSafariViewController offers.

Comment: It's an interesting question but it's too broad. You'd need to share some techniques that you've tried (like playing with the request caching options, for example) so that we can help you further.

Comment: tried with the configuration Setting "suppressesIncrementalRendering", didn't help much. Caching didn't make much difference either.

Comment: @GuyKogus Did you get any leads?